# Pillow installed but not identified (Mac OS Yosemite)

Tags: osx-yosemite, python-imaging-library

I Installed pillow using brew, and when I try to repeat the isntallation I see it's there:

```
brew install Homebrew/python/pillow
Warning: pillow-2.7.0 already installed
```

But when I try to load it into a script I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named Image
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try removing the brew installation of Pillow, and install via pip: `pip install Pillow`. Make sure you have dependencies first: `brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2`. More info: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/installation.html#mac-os-x-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python` usually looks for `Pillow` under normal site package installs. Here's what I would do to get a minimal `Pillow` setup where `python` should be guaranteed to see it:

```
sudo easy_install pip
pip install Pillow
```

I think it may also be possible to just do:

```
sudo easy_install Pillow
```

but `pip` is a bit more user friendly if you're planning on using more `python` scripts that might have dependencies.

Note: another issue you might be running into is if you're trying to use the Homebrew `python` but are ending up using the base OSX install of it instead. Make sure `which python` is showing you what you expect it to be.